# String Checker, Invalid Input - Python

Tags: python

It won't print do not leave username blank as it is invalid input when I press enter(blank input)

```
def strchecker(question):
    valid=False
    while not valid:
        user_Name = input(question)
        if user_Name!="":
            valid=True
            return user_name
        else:
            print("Do no leave username blank")

print("*************Welcome to the Te Reo Maori Quiz***************")
user_Name = str(input("Please enter your username"))
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  If you are using Python 2, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: You are never running your function `strchecker`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually called the function; that's probably why it's not working. Try this:

```
def strchecker(question):
    while True:
        user_Name = input(question)
        if user_Name:
            return user_Name  # Make sure to capitalize the N in user_Name
            break
        else:
            print("Do no leave username blank")

print("*************Welcome to the Te Reo Maori Quiz***************")
user_Name = strchecker("Please enter your username")
```

This should work.

Comment: One redundancy I would remove in your post (and the OP's) is re-assigning the user_Name variable within `strchecker`. You don't need to do that

Comment: @Jade make sure you're careful about naming your variables! :). `user_Name` is different than `user_name`